# XML schema field

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have this element defined in my schema:

```
<xs:element name="Price" minOccurs="0">                                                                                         
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="\d{1,}\.\d{2}" />
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

In my XML file I have, this tag defined, is it valid?

```
<Price/>
```

Or should have been populated with a value, like this?

```
<Price>0.1</Price>
```

My take is that in XML  shouldn't be defined at all.

Comment: Have you tried pasting it into http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/

Comment: _"My take is that in XML shouldn't be defined at all."_ - what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither element would be valid.

The restriction pattern in the XSD says that `Price` should be one or more digits followed by a period followed by two digits.  Neither `Price` matches that pattern.

An example of a `Price` element that would be valid would be:

```
<Price>0.12</Price>
```